# Como renomear o título e os valores da legenda no fviz_cluster()

Tags: r, ggplot2, legenda-de-gráfico, k-means

Estou trabalhando com k-means e, portanto, preciso gerar gráficos intuitivos.

Contudo, o gráfico gerado pela função `fviz_cluster()` não está respondendo à funções usuais em objetos ggplot. Na tentativa de modificar o título da legenda, por exemplo, ele adiciona outra legenda. Além disso, não consigo renomear os valores da legenda para nomes de minha determinação.

```
# Data

data("iris")
iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, -5])

# K-means clusters

km.res <- kmeans(iris.scaled, 3, nstart = 10)

# Visualize

library(factoextra)
pl_stack <- fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5],ellipse.type = "norm") +
scale_fill_discrete(name="Experimental\nCondition",
                  breaks=c("1", "2", "3"),
                  labels=c("Control", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2"))

pl_stack
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que foi gerado uma outra legenda em lugar de modificar a existente. Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `factoextra::fviz_cluster` é só uma [wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function) para a função `ggpubr::ggscatter`. Portanto, basta não mapear a cor e a forma dos pontos explicitamente para que a legenda não desejada não apareça. O código abaixo resolve isso, utilizando as funções `scale_colour_discrete` e `scale_shape_discrete`, respectivamente. Estas duas funções fazem parte do pacote `ggplot2`.

```
fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5], ellipse.type = "norm") +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  scale_shape_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Experimental\nCondition",
                      breaks=c("1", "2", "3"),
                      labels=c("Control", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2"))

pl_stack
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]